# Compare data from two tabs in browser. Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have the items with a price on the first page and after a click on the "View Deal" button, opens the new tab with the second page, on the second page I have all info with price about this. My main goal is to compare these prices, but I have a problem with this.

here method from the second page and on this method I have the exception No such element, it seems like a driver isn't transferred to this tab or page, also if add the driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(1)); then I have the Null pointer exception

```
  `public int parsePriceOnProductPage(){
    // driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(1));
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(bookNowBtn));
    String offerPriceValue = offerPriceProductPage.toString();
    String onlyNumbers = offerPriceValue.replaceAll("[^\\d]", "");
    int offerPrice_val = Integer.parseInt(onlyNumbers);
    return offerPrice_val;
}`
```

This the previous method in the test from the first page and here I send the driver to the second page

```
`public ProductPage clickOnDeal(){
    viewDealBtn.get(1).click();
    return new ProductPage(driver,wait);
}`
```

and here I compare this prices

```
public boolean comparePriceOnHomePageWithProductPage(){
        if(homePage.parsePriceFromSelectedDealOnHomePage() == productPage.parsePriceOnProductPage()){
            return true;
        }else if (homePage.parsePriceFromSelectedDealOnHomePage() > productPage.parsePriceOnProductPage()){
            System.out.println("The price on the Home Page more than on the Product Page on the $"+ (homePage.parsePriceFromSelectedDealOnHomePage() - productPage.parsePriceOnProductPage()) );
        } else {
            System.out.println("The price on the Home Page less than on the Product Page on the $"+ (productPage.parsePriceOnProductPage() - homePage.parsePriceFromSelectedDealOnHomePage()) );
        } return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to get windows handles , it will handles of the tab opened , you can switch between the tabs using below code

```
    ArrayList<String> tabs2 = new ArrayList<String> (driver.getWindowHandles());
    driver.switchTo().window(tabs2.get(1));
    driver.switchTo().window(tabs2.get(0));
    driver.close();
```

Comment: I have this row in parent class     ArrayList<String> tabs2 = new ArrayList<String> (driver.getWindowHandles());                                                                                                            I change this but didn't help, I cant do anything on the second tab

Comment: Change the order usetabs2.get(0) if you where using there other way

Comment: Are you sure you are running the driver gethandles after the new tab or window is opened ?

Comment: Check the tabs2 length  ,tabs2.length verify it's 2

Comment: Yes, I'm running the driver after the new tab opens, but I didn't check the length, try this today

Answer (score 0):

Exact scenario I has tried in my machine. Please find below my code. Have you used as below and still it is not working?

```
public class testclass {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

        driver.get("https://www.amazon.co.uk/");

        Thread.sleep(3000);

        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[.='Fire TV Stick Lite']"));
        Actions act = new Actions(driver);

        act.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).click(element).keyUp(Keys.CONTROL).build().perform();
       // driver.get("http://google.com");
        Thread.sleep(3000);

        ArrayList<String> tabs2 = new ArrayList<String> (driver.getWindowHandles());
            driver.switchTo().window(tabs2.get(1));
        System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
        secondtab t = new secondtab(driver);
        t.searchGoogle();
    }
}


package boots.uk.dps.pages.base;

import com.boots.thor.base.ExtendedWebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;

import java.util.List;

public class secondtab {
    private WebDriver driver;

    public secondtab(WebDriver driver){
        this.driver =  driver;
    }

    public void searchGoogle(){
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='buy-now-button']")).click();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't see any mistake in your code. I think you are using the page object model. In your scenario, try using as below, it should work.

driver.findElement(By...);